# I cannot click software menu, can only use menu via keyboard

Tags: menu, analysis, tableau-api, spss

I have a weird problem that after installing software apps on my computer, I cannot seem to be able to click on the menus.

I can actually click on the menus but this doesn't invoke the menu commands, i.e perform analyses or show drop down menu items. I can however access these commands using the respective keyboard shortcuts.

I can use many apps on my computer but this problem pertains to specific analytical apps, namely SPSS and Tableau.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: For SPSS there has been a few complaints on the forums about the toolbar (in V22 I think) crashing or dissapearing. See [this thread](http://spssx-discussion.1045642.n5.nabble.com/V22-crashed-now-no-toolbar-td5725877.html) for talk about OSX and Windows solutions. This is more a tech support problem though.

Comment: This isn't a programming problem, and hence isn't on-topic for a programming forum. You might get help at _SuperUser_, but you'd probably need to add more detail. I can't see what OS you are on, for example - a fairly critical piece of information.

Answer (score 0):

If this is happening in multiple apps, it must be an issue with your OS/hardware or something general and not an issue with specific applications.